# Standardize Regressors in sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression

I'm working with sklearn and I'm wondering how StandardScaler() is used appropriately. I build a function that allows to switch between Ridge and Lasso regression as well as takes the alpha value, the regressors X and the predicted variable Y. All regressors should be standardized.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, Lasso
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler() # Standardize regressors by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance

def do_penalized_regression(X, y, penalty, type):
    if type == "ridge":
        lm = Ridge(alpha = penalty, normalize=False)
    elif type == "lasso":
        lm = Lasso(alpha = penalty, normalize=False)
lm.scaler.fit(X,y)
return lm
```

Is this the way to go or should I standardize the regressors in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html):

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, Lasso
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline


model = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), lm)

model.fit(X, y)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, after some iterations that worked perfectly fine!